# C# UWP UploadOperation BackgroundUploader Unable to find response

Tags: c#, uwp

```
                string boundray = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
                string url = HttpDomainHandling(currentUser.DomainURL) + API + "&is_multi_part_upload=true";
                string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\"\r\n" + "Content-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n", boundray, "file", file.Name, "application/octet-stream");
                string footer = string.Format("\r\n--{0}--\r\n", boundray);

                Stream headerStream = GenerateStreamFromString(header);
                Stream footerStream = GenerateStreamFromString(footer);
                Stream dataStream = await sfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

                MemoryStream fileDataStream = new MemoryStream();
                await headerStream.CopyToAsync(fileDataStream);
                await dataStream.CopyToAsync(fileDataStream);
                await footerStream.CopyToAsync(fileDataStream);
                fileDataStream.Position = 0;

                IInputStream stream = fileDataStream.AsInputStream();

                BackgroundUploader backgroundUploader = new BackgroundUploader();
                backgroundUploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundray);
                backgroundUploader.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", Constants.FELIXSESSIONID + "=" + currentUser.SessionID);
                backgroundUploader.Method = "POST";

                UploadOperation uploadOpration = await backgroundUploader.CreateUploadFromStreamAsync(new Uri(url), stream);

                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CheckUploadStatus(uploadOpration, progressEvent, cts));
                var result = await uploadOpration.StartAsync();
                ResponseInformation info = uploadOpration.GetResponseInformation();
                return info;
```

Unable to find json response in result and response information..where can i get this response...

I am trying to upload file to my server.. and its return upload data in json format..

Comment: Did you get any exception information when debugging? Did you have a 'ExceptionHandle' method to monitor the upload operation like the official [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BackgroundTransfer/cs/BackgroundTransfer/Scenario2_Upload.xaml.cs#L322).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the Answer

- BackgroundUploader is used when you want to upload something on IP or some address and you don't want the response string from server...
- BackgroundUploader can return just status code and successfully or error message info

if you want to upload something and you want you response string example JSON or XML...
need to use [UWP HTTPCLIENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient)

```
//Create an HTTP client object
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();

//Add a user-agent header to the GET request. 
var headers = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;

//The safe way to add a header value is to use the TryParseAdd method and verify the return value is true,
//especially if the header value is coming from user input.
string header = "ie";
if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
}

header = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
if (!headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd(header))
{
    throw new Exception("Invalid header value: " + header);
}

Uri requestUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");

//Send the GET request asynchronously and retrieve the response as a string.
Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
string httpResponseBody = "";

try
{
    //Send the GET request
    httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri);
    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    httpResponseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    httpResponseBody = "Error: " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") + " Message: " + ex.Message;
}
```